# How to use d3 range scale?

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible in d3 to color objects using custom color range values?

I have two json :
One is having values:

```
[
  {
    "area": "amsterdamn",
    "KPIValue": 98.46
  },
  {
    "area": "brunei",
    "KPIValue": 95.98
  }
]
```

Another is having range:

```
[
  {
    "lowerRange": 0,
    "upperRange": 90,
    "sn": 1,
    "color": "331fcf"
  },
  {
    "lowerRange": 90,
    "upperRange": 100,
    "sn": 2,
    "color": "004F00"
  }
]
```

How do I fill a path using color in a range using values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quantile scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#quantile-scales) should do the job.

```
// define a variable thresholds as an array of threshold values
// using the lower range
var thresholds = range.map(function(rec) { return rec.lowerRange})

// define a variable colors as an array of color values
var colors = range.map(function(rec) { return rec.color})

// define the scale
var t = d3.scale.quantile().domain(thresholds).range(colors)

// use it
t(KPIValue) // returns the corresponding color
```

Here is a [working demo](https://tonicdev.com/5694f8711f12ba0d000d405e/56960af333b2840c007ff099)

Comment: upvoted but how do I pass pathname example : function(d,i) {return color(i)}) because color is depended on pathname. When I pass d I get whole d3 path object and not current path.

Comment: Please share the code where you would like to use the color scale.